Usage of storage from material handling library causes NullPointerException problem
I have been trying to to the storage object from the material handling library in my process simulation, but whenever my agent (forklift) puts in one pallet of cargo into my storage, i get this error:
Exception during discrete event execution:
Cannot invoke "com.anylogic.engine.markup.Level.getSpace()" because "" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.anylogic.engine.markup.Level.getSpace()" because "" is null
at com.anylogic.libraries.modules.level_system.LevelDataStorage.getLevelData(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.LevelSystem.(Unknown Source)
...
...
I can't seem to find this function in the java code for main or simulation. Does anyone know what this problem is?

have you tried it with a trivial toy model? If it works there, you need to figure out the differences. Hard to say just from the error. Looks like some agents are not in a space, maybe you instantiated them elsewhere, manually or wrongly...

@Benjamin Thank you for your help! Turns out I forgot to instantiate my agent properly at a split

feel free to post the full solution as your own answer. This way, others can benefit with similar issues in the future :)
